# How to Deal with Core Data Relationships in Offline sync - Azure Mobile Services iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, azure-mobile-services

I am using **Offline sync - Azure Mobile Services** for iOS and I have a lot of relationships in Core Data entities. As you know in Core Data we assign an entity to another entity's relationship but in **Offline sync - Azure Mobile Services** we convert NSManagedObject to NSDictionary for inserting in a table/entity. So I don't know how to deal with Core Data Relationships in the Azure API. Please help me by explaining Core Data's 1:1, 1:N and N:N relationships in **Offline sync - Azure Mobile Services**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services does not support relationships between SQL tables.  IN addition, the Client SDK uploads changes individually, so you cannot enforce the relationship.

Comment: Thanks Adrian.

Btw I have also asked from the Azure team and their reply was following:
"The offline sync feature in Mobile Apps does not support Core Data relationships. So, you would have to create separate tables within Core Data to manage these relationships, and then sync those tables. Another option is to nest the data together into one big object."

Comment: I'm on that team - we're saying the same thing.

Comment: @AdrianHall any articles by Azure team on how manage relationships on Azure easy Tables and iOS client?